# Maven Plugin For CodeSniffing

Tags: java, maven-3, java-ee-7

I am just wondering if there is a maven plugin that parses source code and alert developers of non conformance coding style?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven checkstyle plugin could be what you are after.
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/

Comment: By any chance are you aware of different similar plugins, I'd really like to have multi options to choose from. Your response was good starting point thanks @Kevin D